# Developing facebook webhook app locally

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, koala

I'm trying to create my first facebook-webhook app. I'm obviously doing it on localhost (with app served using ngrok). The facebook app i'm using for that is a "test app" created just to make it able to develop that locally.

What i'm trying to create is basically about listening for new posts on a page and parsing their content. Following the official guide, i've added a "Webhooks" addon for my test app and configured it to post all the hooks to my local app url (through ngrok). That part works fine so far.

Problem occurs when i'm trying to subscribe my app to page events. Following official guide (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/implementation#page_access_token - `Page access token` section), i can't do that without requesting a permission for `pages_messaging` permission BUT the official guide says i can generate an access token for any of fanpages owned by me, which will have such permission inclued.

> A Page Access Token is based on an app, page and user and has scopes associated with it. In the developer app, go to the Messenger tab. Select your page and generate a token. A Page Access Token is based on an app, page and user and has scopes associated with it. In the developer app, go to the Messenger tab. Select your page and generate a token. This will generate a Page Access Token with the manage_pages, pages_messaging, and pages_messaging_phone_number scopes.

So, following this, i've created such token but when i'm trying to add a subscription to my fanpage (using that endpoint: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/subscribed_apps/), facebook responds with:

> type: OAuthException, code: 230, message: (#230) permission pages_messaging is required to register webhook for messages or deliveries [HTTP 403]

So it seems that the access token i've generated for my test app in developer portal does not have such permissions included. Or am i misunderstanding something? Any clarification much appreciated, i'm really confused.

Comment: Debug the access token, to see what permissions it contains – https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ If it turns out the process from within the app dashboard is not working as expected, then try creating a token manually in Graph API Explorer (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer), by selecting your app and then “Get Token”

Comment: Check this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38909357/webhooks-failing-with-invalid-scopes-pages-messaging-subscriptions/38911154#38911154

Comment: @CBroe If you post your comment as an answer I'd upvote it. I'd point people directly to the Access Token Debugger though: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/.